# Variable result isn't found

Tags: java, bluej

Program is pretty simple, and it's self-assigned so no, it's not homework.

User is supposed to input three numbers, show the squared numbers and also show the sum of the numbers.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CompSquares {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        Scanner s= new Scanner( System.in); 
        int num1;
        System.out.println(" Enter a number please.");
        num1 = s.nextInt();
        int num2;
        System.out.println("One more."); 
        num2 = s.nextInt();
        int num3;
        System.out.println("Last one.");
        num3 = s.nextInt();

        System.out.println( "The numbers squared are " + Square( num1, num2, num3));
        System.out.println("The sum of these numbers is " + Sum(result)); 
    }

    private static double Square ( int num1, int num2, int num3) {

        if ( num1 > 0) {
            num1 *= num1;
            System.out.println (num1);} 
            else {
                System.out.println( "Enter a correct number, please.");
            }
            if ( num2 > 0){ 
                 num2 *= num2;
                System.out.println (num2); }
                else {
                    System.out.println("Really? Again. Do the right thing this time, jeez.");
                }
            if ( num3 > 0){
                num3*=num3;
                System.out.println (num3);}
                else {
                    System.out.println("Just make it more then one!!");
                }
            }

    public static int Sum ( int num1, int num2, int num3, int result) {
        result = num1 + num2 + num3;
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sum required this aruments  ( int num1, int num2, int num3, int result) and you pass just result, second: what is result you don't have result variable in your main

Answer (score 1):

In the main method:

```
 System.out.println("The sum of these numbers is " + Sum(result));
```

`result` has not been declared in any scope visible to `main()`.

Instead of `Sum` taking an `int result` parameter, I think that you meant for `Sum` to `return` the result. Without giving you the *entire* answer, start here:

```
public static int Sum (int num1, int num2, int num3) {
    int result = num1 + num2 + num3;
    System.out.println(result);
    return result;
}
```

This will also solve another compiler error (the fact that `Sum` in the original code does not return anything, but it's declared return type is `int`).

Comment: Let me know if my partial answer is not enough to get you unstuck, and I can give you all the code. But this is meant to be a learning exercise for you, right? `:)`

Comment: ah thanks!! i like it better when i'm given hints rather than the whole answer.

Comment: yeah, i'm trying to complete one of my new year resolutions (learn java) so i've been assigning myself multiple programs but as you can see, i still have a looooong way to go, lol.

Comment: fixed the compile errors, but now it's in a never ending loop and only returns result. whoops?

Answer (score 0):

1) Variable result isn't found.

It is due to your main method not declaring what result is?
you have passed result to method sum.
here:
System.out.println("The sum of these numbers is " + Sum(result));

2) method sum defined with four parameters but passing just one during the call.

3) Either method should return something based on computation done, or  declare it void. Both method square and sum are defined to return something but not doing so.

Here is the link to 
Java tutorials https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/
also would suggest going through sample programs and examples to enrich your​ learning.

Happy coding.